# How does Apache know which certificate to use when multiple certificates are available?

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Following is the scenario:

1. There is an intermediate CA in the application, lets say CA1.
2. CA1 signs the server certificate and client certificate(which would be made available to the client upon setting up the client endpoint)
3. Both server and client have CA1 in their truststore and communication happens good.
4. Now CA1 is about to expire
5. Can I keep both old and new CA certs and server certificates in the same directory? (because I don't want client applications running to fail, they still need to be able to make communication using old certificate till admin updates the client)
6. If so, how does apache choose which certificate to send back in ServerHello message?

Comment: I guess the RootCA should create a new cert for the IntermediateCA, then the intermediateCA can create new certs for both the client and the server. As long as both parties trust the RootCA, it should work with no problems.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond the intermediate CA can be signed by any third party CA by the client and rootCA of the third party is unavailable in the application truststore..

Comment: They should have the *signer* of CA1 in their truststore, or the signer's signer, as far up as you can go.

Comment: @Vishnu Both end should trust the RootCA, otherwise it is a unique system with unique problems, which means the common patterns and solutions wouldn't work in it